# Trying to get Unity to set properties from a config file

Tags: c#, configuration, properties, unity-container

I have Unity up and running but I'm trying to figure out one last thing to get it working like the internally developed DI engine we're working to replace.

Once I've got the object instantiated and some properties set from one config file, how do I get it to fill a whole bunch of properties/fields in the object from an XML file that's in a folder down a couple of levels from the root?

If you could point me in the direction of some how-toos on this I'd greatly appreciate it.

This is one of the files that worked with the old system:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<component xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://mamc-sharepoint.army.mil/sites/Informatics/mamcDev/Schemas/MAMC.EnterpriseLibrary/DIComponent_v1.0.0.1.xsd">
  <type name="MAB.Test.Framework.WebTest.WebTestSettings"
        assembly="${Assemblies[MAB.Test.Framework]}"/>
  <properties>
    <!--Some semi active settings. Intended to be used to keep the browser running between test methods.-->
    <add name="StartServerIfNotRunning">true</add>
    <add name="StopServerIfRunning">true</add>
    <add name="ServerLeaveRunning">false</add>

    <!--Instructions on which browser to use for the testing.-->
    <!--iexplorer, firefox, htmlunit-->
    <add name="BrowserString">firefox</add>

    <!--
    BrowserURL is the base URL for the application under test.  
    Remember to include the forward slash at the end of the URL.
    -->
    <add name="BrowserURL">https://www.google.com/</add>

    <!--The default amount of timeout we're going to use for waiting for actions to happen.-->
    <add name="BaseTimeout">4000</add>
    <!--A modifier that slows down or speeds up the playback depending on the environments behavior.-->
    <add name="TimeoutMultiplier">1</add>
  </properties>

</component>
```

Thanks,

MArk B.

Comment: If you know how to do property injection why don't you set all of your object's properties that way? Just to keep those separate xml files?

Comment: Hi Sabastian,

Well, I don't exactly know.
I'm just getting a handle on this stuff so I can't say one way or the other. I don't think I made it clear before but I'm trying to replace an existing system that did it that way. The web.config would indicate the folder where the other config files were. A file there would say where everything else was. The IOC would then load the right file based on the name of the object.
I don't really get how the old system works and no one else here does. That's why we're wanting to replace it.
I'll look into the Property Injection some more.

Comment: How about this:
I want to unit test a User object with 3 users. I want to populate those users from external XML files. I would like to be able to specify which files those are in a separate file. I'd also like to be able to add a User information XML file and add that name to the manager file so I don't have to change the code.

Is that confusing enough yet?

Comment: Actually, what I'm trying to do is, per the example XML file above, have several config files set up with parameters needed to point at different environments under test. I then want to specify which of those files to use using a setting in a different config file. One each for Dev, Test, Pre-Prod and Production.

Answer (score 0):

This is too much for a simple comments thus:

What kind of objects should be initialized by the settings in the XML files you showed above?

This looks like environment settings not settings for objects like `User`.

Are these settings for test environments only? Or also for production environments? [Visual Studio supports different debug and release config files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx0123s5.aspx). It is even possible to [transform the web.config file for different build configurations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_webdevelopment_topic4.aspx).

And finally: [This is an example on how to read settings](http://svenerikmatzen.wordpress.com/2010/09/17/simpler-configuration-sections/) from your config file without the hustle of writing custom section handlers.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian.
That may be the way I go. It's this working in an area that's over my head and with a legacy system that isn't very well documented that's getting to me.
To answer your question(s): I'm actually trying to do a couple of things. One is as you say environment settings. The other is the test data User example that's given in the comments. Our existing system doesn't seem to differentiate much in how they are treated hence some of my confusion.